# Updating Grafana configuration file to configure custom SMTP settings

Tags: kubernetes, grafana, prometheus, kubernetes-helm, azure-aks

I used HELM to install the Prometheus operator and kube-prometheus into my kubernetes cluster using the following commands:

```
helm install coreos/prometheus-operator --name prometheus-operator --namespace monitoring --set rbacEnable=false
helm install coreos/kube-prometheus --name kube-prometheus --set global.rbacEnable=false --namespace monitoring
```

Everything is running fine, however, I want to set up email alerts and in order to do so I must configure the SMTP settings in "custom.ini" file according to the grafana website. I am fairly new to Kuberenetes and using HELM charts, therefore I have no idea which command I would use to access this file or make updates to it? Is it possible to do so without having to redeploy?

Can anyone provide me with a command to update custom values?

Answer (score 1):

You could pass `grafana.env` [value](https://github.com/helm/charts/tree/master/stable/grafana#configuration) to add [SMTP-related settings](http://docs.grafana.org/installation/configuration/):

GF_SMTP_ENABLED=true,GF_SMTP_HOST,GF_SMTP_USER and GF_SMTP_PASSWORD

should do the trick. The `prometheus-operator` chart relies on the upstream `stable/grafana` chart (although, [still using the 1.25 version](https://github.com/helm/charts/blob/master/stable/prometheus-operator/requirements.lock))

Comment: Do you set these variables from directly inside the grafana container? What is the command to set the env value?

Comment: No you can just pass it on while deploying the Helm chart of prom-operator:



helm install stable/prometheus-operator --name prometheus-operator --namespace monitoring --set rbacEnable=true,grafana.env.GF_SMTP_ENABLED=true,grafana.env.GF_SMTP_HOST=host #and so on